# How can I iterate CASE statements in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I would like to write the a query in mySQL that has the following form:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN <column name> = 1  THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END as "column_1",
    CASE
        WHEN <column name> = 2 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END as "column_2",
    CASE
        WHEN <column name> = 3 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END as "column_3"
    FROM <table name>;
```

I would like to write this query for a large number of cases (approximately 1000 cases), such that 1000 new columns are created that satisfy the conditions given above. How can I iterate this process in mySQL so that I don't have to write each line manually as I have done above (where there are only 3 cases)?

Comment: You do your iterations in a stored procedure or an outside scripting program to dynamically write the SQL for you. Once written, then you execute the dynamically created sql statement.

Comment: Generate the text above with any scripting language at hand, MySql will do.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Boolean expressions implicitly evaluate to 0 or 1, meaning `WHEN <column name> = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` can be reduced to simply `<column name> = 1`. Also, field names are conventionally surrounded by backticks, not double quotes.

Comment: @JNevill: Is this possible without using an outside scripting pogroming? i.e. within MySQL?

Comment: @Serg I'm not sure I understand; do you want me to compile the above script for my data in MySQL and show you the out-put?

Comment: Within a stored procedure, possibly. I've not worked with mySQL stored procedures, but in other RDBMSs it's totally doable, so I assume it's the same. That being said, stored procedures are just scripting, so either way you are going to have to write code to dynamically generate SQL and then execute that statement.

Comment: @shmosel the new column created will be Boolean; however, the column in the condition i.e. <column name> = n, where n is some number is of integer value

Comment: If the number of cases is static and doesn't change each time you execute this statement, then you might just be better off building this sql statement by hand. I've used excel in the past to stitch together ugly SQL statements where there are bits that are repeated over and over and over again.

Comment: You're missing the point. The expression `<column name> = 1` evaluates to 1 or 0, without all the `CASE WHEN...` boilerplate. (I mean to include `CASE` in my previous comment.)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be appropriate, but if you can live with one column of output (as a string rather than as multiple columns), then you might be able to do the following:

```
select t.id,
       group_concat( (case when t.column = v.value then '1' else '0' end) order by v.ordering) as string_flags
from (select 1 as ordering, 1 as value union all
      select 2, 2 union all
      . . .
     ) v cross join
     t
group by t.id;
```

This is just an idea.  Performance is an issue, but it also gets around issues with the maximum number of columns in a row.